# How to represent missing values in QGIS graduated style?

Tags: qgis, style, representation

I added a csv layer on qgis, and I changed the style so that the color of the point changes according to the the salinity of each sample (graduated). However, there are some samples for which I have no salinity value, and then they disappear from the map. I would like those points to remain, but with a grey color. Is there a way to include missing values representation in the graduated style?